# Error while uploading big size images in android

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory

In my android application, the user can select an image from the gallery and upload it on the application. I've achieved this by using onActivityResult() in this way:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
        if (requestCode == 10) {
             Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();

             int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
             picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             cursor.close();

             image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
         }
    }
}
```

and everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to upload a very big size image, I get the java.lang.outOfMemory error when the BitmapFactory.decodeFile() method is called. I would reduce the size of the image if I could, but I get the problem even before I can start working with my Bitmap. So how can I upload those images?

Comment: You have to decode a smaller subsampled version of your bitmap. Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Where are you uploading an image? I only see you trying to put a file in a Bitmap. Why? If you want to upload a file then just upload it. Do not use BitmapFactory or Bitmap.

Comment: @greenapps With uploading I just mean putting it into a Bitmap so I can use the image in my application. I need the Bitmap because I have to draw it on a canvas. But my problem is solved now.